# TOSCA is programmed with which programming language?

Tags: testing, tosca

Please excuse me if this is the wrong place to ask this question.

I wanted to know in which programming language does the testing tool TOSCA is programmed in. To be little specific, is it c++ or java??

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: It should be noted that this question is asking which language was used to develop Tosca itself...   However, when a Tosca user is "writing code" within Tosca for automated tests, the "language" is unlike any text based line by line code...  It's more like developing a excel spreadsheet...

Comment: that is true... but I was more interested in knowing in which language the platform itself was developed. I got to know that the components like TBox, etc are programmed with C# but in the classical platform it was VB6.  @TrimbleEpic

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is neither C++ nor Java.
Tricentis Tosca is developed in C# for the majority of its parts.

Answer (score 0):

TOSCA is based on the COM Window objects. Also you can use C# if you want to code for TOSCA.